# How do Change The File Icon color in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, file-icons

So I was just wondering if there was any way to change the active file's text and icon color, like it happens on atom, for VSCode. I tried doing something like `sideBar.Foreground": "#ff0000`. But it changes the everything's foreground, not only the active file icons. Is there any way to only change the active one's foreground?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.